# Most efficient way to query a json array?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON array and each object has a number representing a category. For example:

```
data: [
{
    "code": "336413"
},
{
    "code": "336413"
},
{
    "code": "331318"
},
```

What would be the most efficient way to pick out the objects with a specific code number and delete or leave behind the rest? My dataset has thousands of objects, so efficiency is important.

Comment: Do you want to delete one of the json or one of the `code` number?

Comment: The end goal is to only have objects with the correct code values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using generator expression to get the values you want.

```
test_list= [
{
    "code": "333413"
},
{
    "code": "333413"
},
{
    "code": "331318"
}]

code = "333413"

a = (item for item in test_list if item["code"] == code)

print(list(a))
```

output:

```
>>[{'code': '333413'}, {'code': '333413'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension will be efficient enough especially given that your dataset fits in memory.

EDIT: Didn't see @Errol's answer but yeah pretty much the same thing.

```
data = [
    {"code": "1"},
    {"code": "2"},
    {"code": "3"},
    {"code": "4"},
    {"code": "5"},
    {"code": "6"},
    {"code": "7"},
    {"code": "8"},
    {"code": "9"},
    {"code": "10"},
]


def main():
    codes_to_keep = {"1", "7", "10"}
    filtered_data = [document for document in data if document.get("code") in codes_to_keep]
    print(filtered_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which will output: `[{'code': '1'}, {'code': '7'}, {'code': '10'}]`

Answer (score 0):

I use two Idea to do this,Idea1 is other person's idea,Idea2 is my idea.
I run this code in my computer

**edit,I try to use 10000.And change my test code.Thanks Vishal Singh and Cireo point out my fault and carelessness**

I have created 10000 jsons.
Here is the test code:

```
import time
import copy
import random
def Idea1():
    codes_to_keep = []
    for i in range(5):
        codes_to_keep.append(str(random.randint(0,10000)))
    start = time.time()
    filtered_data = [document for document in data if document.get("code") in codes_to_keep]
    end = time.time()

    print("Idea1 running time: %f"%(end-start))
    print(filtered_data)

def Idea2():
    codes_to_keep = []
    for i in range(5):
        codes_to_keep.append(str(random.randint(0, 10000)))
    start = time.time()
    RemoveIndex = []
    for i in range(len(data2)):
        if not data2[i]["code"] in codes_to_keep:
            RemoveIndex.append(i)

    for i in reversed(RemoveIndex):
        del data2[i]

    end = time.time()
    print("Idea2 running time:%f"% (end - start))
    print(data2)

data = []
for i in range(10000):
    Tempdict = {}
    Tempdict["code"] = str(i)
    data.append(Tempdict)

data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)

# for i in range(1000000):
#     Tempdict = {}
#     Tempdict["code"] = str(i)
#     data2.append(Tempdict)

Idea1()

Idea2()
```

And the time they waste don't far from each other.I recommend their ideas.My idea is a little complicated and often slower than theirs.

Comment: This answer is misleading and confusing.  Among other things: you modify the list while you iterate over it, which breaks plenty of things; you use the same list in both threads; you implement the opposite logic you describe; you run both simultaneously in threads, which will distort both results.  In the end your runtimes are almost identical and about 1ms. Sorry for being direct =/

Comment: removing elements creates an overhead of reindexing the `list`. If you have many items to remove and a large `list` then it's a bad idea. And also you are removing the element from the same `list` you are iterating, which will produce unexpected results.

Comment: @VishalSingh But their idea will create a new list.I test `1000000` json,and find my idea is `0.062972`,and their idea is `0.085902`.And I changed my test code.

Comment: data2 = data won't help. you are shallow copying the list. It will still have unexpected results because removing the element from data will also remove it from data2. You can use slicing `for i in data[:]` to iterate over the data list and also modify it.

Comment: @VishalSingh And now I create a new dict.

Comment: deepcopy is ok.

Comment: Your logic is still off, you remove the matches instead of the other ones.  You also use get for 1 and [] for 2, which have different speeds.

Comment: @Cireo I find a big problem in my code.It is not recommended to change list when loop it.I use a new way to do this and edit my post.

Comment: Glad we were able to help, and thank you for accepting the constructive criticism gracefully